Time complexity of an HAMT
A Hashed Array Mapped Trie has a time complexity of log32(n).
According to the paper referred by this implementation, the 32 comes from the cardinality of the alphabet, which in this case is a 32 bits integer.
If the search is through a maximum of 6 or 7 hops according to the algorithm, why is it log32?

Hint: what's log_32(2**32)?

Also, please make sure that your question is understandable and answerable without relying on external links. Links go stale, content linked to changes or vanishes, URIs go dead, domains change owners. Your question should still make sense in a 100 years.

This question doesn't depend on the links. A HAMT is a well-known, widely used data structure. The links are supporting, not critical for understanding.

Are you aware that O(log32(n)) is identical to O(log(n)) or O(ln(n)) ? In terms of "big-O", a constant factor does not matter, and a base change from one log base to another requires only a constant factor.

@DocBrown yeah, but it's specified as log_32 in many places including language implementations, papers, lectures etc.

This case is a little confusing for asymptotic complexity, because HAMT implementations choose a fixed hash size and fanout, usually 32. So if you have 232 possible hashes (a fixed 32-bit hash size), and each level of the trie divides those hashes into 32 subtries (a 32 fanout), your trie has a maximum depth of log32(232), or 6.4.
But because a new level is not created unless you have a collision, the depth is proportional to the size of the input, assuming your hash has a good uniform distribution.
In practice, O(log32 n) is not much slower than nominally O(1) hash table algorithms, and HAMTs are popular because they use space much more efficiently, without expensive reallocations.

I think the calculation I have done to figure out the log base but for some reason wasn't posted is (2^d)^(1/(d/5)) which is 32. d is the binary digit count, and n is 2^d. We receive it by dividing the number into 5 binary digits at a time per the algorithm, and it is recursive so it multiples by itself every 5 digits, which is where the power of d/5 comes from. Then you take the root because you technically divide it by the number. The result is the log base.

In other words: log_x(n) = y; where x is the base and y is the number of computations; n = x^y; n^(1/y) = x; n = 2^d where d is the binary digits required to represent n; y is the computation which recurses d/5 times. (2^d)^(1/(d/5)) = x; (2^d)^(5/d); 2^5 = x.
